# Golang regex: doesn't work with underscore

Tags: regex, go

I create this code to get the dates using a regex but it doesn't get it:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)
func main() {
    strings := []string{
        "mid_monthly_2023_10_mac",
        "mid_monthly_2023_11_mac",
        "mid_monthly-20-04-end",
        "mid_monthly-19-6-end",
    }
    pattern := `\b(?:\d{4}[-_]\d{1,2}[-_]\d{1,2}|\d{2}[-_]\d{1,2}[-_]\d{4})\b`
    for _, str := range strings {
        re := regexp.MustCompile(pattern)
        matches := re.FindAllString(str, -1)
        fmt.Println(matches)
    }
}
```

The matches doesn't return anything, any advice.

Comment: Underscore (`_`) is considered part of a word, so you cannot use `\b` if the vague date strings might start/end with underscore (vs dash or white-space)

Comment: Does it mean the dates only follow the `YY-MM` or `YYYY-MM` format?

Comment: Where is the code to get the dates ? If using a regex to get dates and you never get dates, do you claim the regex is bad or having 10 types of dates is bad ?

Comment: I believe all you need is `(?:\D|^)(\d{2}(?:\d{2})?[_-]\d{1,2})(?:\D|$)`, right? See [the **regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/FAzQye/1). `(?:\D|^)` and `(?:\D|$)` are numeric boundaries.

Comment: I guess its still pertinate, what is the date format ? And btw,  matching two groups of any numbers is _not_ a date format, not even close.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression pattern in your code seems to be the issue. It is not matching the date formats you have provided in your strings.I modified regular expression pattern that should match the dates in your strings:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    strings := []string{
        "mid_monthly_2023_10_mac",
        "mid_monthly_2023_11_mac",
        "mid_monthly-20-04-end",
        "mid_monthly-19-6-end",
    }
    pattern := `\b\d{4}[-_]\d{1,2}[-_]\d{1,2}\b|\b\d{2}[-_]\d{1,2}[-_]\d{2}\b`
    for _, str := range strings {
        re := regexp.MustCompile(pattern)
        matches := re.FindAllString(str, -1)
        fmt.Println(matches)
    }
}
```

The modified pattern `\b\d{4}[-_]\d{1,2}[-_]\d{1,2}\b|\b\d{2}[-_]\d{1,2}[-_]\d{2}\b` should match dates in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" or "YY-MM-DD" separated by either hyphens or underscores

please try

for underscore use

```
pattern := `\b\d{4}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}\b|\b\d{2}_\d{1,2}_\d{2}\b`
```

This pattern matches dates in the format "YYYY_MM_DD" or "YY_MM_DD" separated by underscores (_)

Comment: But I wan to use the _ to

Comment: pattern := `\b\d{4}_\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}\b|\b\d{2}_\d{1,2}_\d{2}\b` This pattern matches dates in the format "YYYY_MM_DD" or "YY_MM_DD" separated by underscores (_)

Answer (score 0):

In RegEx the word-boundary (`\b`) includes numbers and **underscore** as part of words.. your examples often include underscore as a suggested boundary, so you need to look for that instead of the `\b` shortcut.

Your RegEx is written for a 3-part date, but your example strings only have two parts.  You either need to make the third part optional, or drop it it entirely from the test, if you want all four strings to match. (You haven't been specific in your request)

Your second two examples don't have 4 digit numbers, but currently both your RegEx tests expect at least one 4 digit number.  (You haven't been specific in your request)

If you're looking for two part where one is always four digits: (only first two will match)

`[-_](\d{4}[-_]\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}[-_]\d{4})[_-]`

If you're looking for two part where one can be four digits: (all four will match)

`[-_](\d{4}[-_]\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}[-_]\d{4}|\d{1,2}[-_]\d{1,2})[_-]`